# In java, does a Thread keep going even if nothing can access it?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

So, you've got a java class ExampleThread that extends Thread.  To make this example simple, let's say that its run() method simply sleep()s for 10 seconds and then prints "Hello World" to the screen.  However, it gets created like so:

```
public void startThread() {
   //Create local variable
   ExampleThread example = new ExampleThread();

   example.start();

}
```

If we call this method and then the main thread goes on to do other things, will the Hello World get printed or not?  Most Java objects cease to exist the moment nothing can refer to them (and nothing can refer to 'example', seeing as it was a local variable). Are running threads different?

Sorry if this has already been asked, I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: The thread will continue.

Comment: Look up daemon and non-daemon threads as well

Comment: okay, okay =) you guys are right. Editing my comment

Comment: `[teach me]` The "access" in Java is counted from a few base locations. Those include static member variables and THREAD STACKS. So a thread is its own accessor. In particular, inside thread you can always say `Thread.currentThread()`, providing you with the access.

Comment: @Arkadiy and that's why I love this site. I learn new stuff every day

Answer (score 0):

> Most Java objects cease to exist the moment nothing can refer to them...

For all practical purposes, that is true, but in reality, there may be an interval of time before the garbage collector reclaims the object.

> ...and nothing can refer to 'example', seeing as it was a local variable

There's your mistake.

First of all, `example` is not the `Thread` object.  `example` is a *variable* that *refers* to the `Thread` object.  `example` exists in the activation record for your `startThread()` call, and it ceases to exist as soon as `startThread()` returns, but the `Thread` object exists on the heap. And,...

...There is another reference to it that is not visible in your program.

The `Thread` object is not a *thread*.  It is merely a proxy for the actual operating system thread that was created when you called `example.start()`.  Before `example.start()` returns, it has created a new operating system thread including the *stack* for that thread.  Somewhere on the stack for the new thread, below the call to the `run()` method, there is a call to a private method with a local variable that refers to the `Thread` object.

That hidden local variable is what keeps the `Thread` from being garbage collected until after `run()` has returned.  Every thread in a Java program has a hidden reference to its own `Thread` object.

Comment: I have to try but a hidden variable pointed to yourself should be regarded as cyclic by the Garbage Collector and therefor your object should still be garbage collected. Or did I understand your explanation in a wrong way?

Comment: @Lothar, The hidden variable is not "pointed to yourself." It is a local variable on the thread's stack, holding a reference to the `Thread` object that controls the thread.  The thread's stack, and the `Thread` object, and the thread itself are three completely different things.  The Java garbage collector considers every local variable on every thread stack to be a _root reference_.  It will never reclaim an object that is referenced by any local variable of any active function call.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't hold a reference to that thread, it still is referenced internally by the `ThreadGroup`. Otherwise you'd be right that the thread would be expected to be destroyed by the Garbage Collector. So no special handling here, but a non-so-obvious reason.

The `daemon` attribute - as mentioned in the comments - has nothing to do here. If only daemon threads are left, the Java Virtual Machine is shutting down but both types of threads are handled in the same way.